# generating errors and access logs in python

Tags: python, logging, web.py

We are realizing that we need error logs and access logs for our service processes. These are long running process like services; they respond to calls made to them.

Hence, we need your help to simply achieve the following:

```
# for developers
from MyLogger import log

log.error 'something bad something wrong'
log.access 'something something'
```

I am thinking of designing this `MyLogger` which will simply redirect an error to stderr and access to stdout, so that I can collect errors to a specific file through configuration for both stderr and stdout.

One more point: these services are nothing but web.py instances.

I guess I'm not looking for a controlling log at various levels, like warn, debug, error, info, etc. My aim is more to have an error log and access log similar to the apache web server. So my developers should not be concerned about using warn, debug, etc. as follows:

```
log.warn msg
log.debug msg
```

This is not required.

I just want to have an error log and an access log similar to that of a web server or service.

Comment: if all you want is to write to a file when every something happens, just write to a file. You don't need a fancy framework/library for that

Comment: pathetic! I thought logging is more than a file write operation.

Comment: @AmolPujari I'm curious why you are posting the abrasive comments, continuously (I saw the other two at the answers that have been deleted since). What is your goal? Are you trolling or are you interested to know how people have solved the problem you described?

Comment: yes @sehe, I am interested to know how people have solved this problem, I as well mentioned that I am not looking for default python logging way, and so wanted to know people's experiences about this. If somebody could explain me +/- of a couple of approaches that would have been great

Answer (score 1):

That "battery" is already included for you in the [Python standard logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

Answer (score 1):

Python ships with the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.